# How to make a HTTPS call with the HTTP connector?

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-component

what is the best way to  make a HTTPS call with the certificate from a HTTP component in mule ? as of now i am using the security tab available in the HTTP component of mule for the purpose .Security TAB available in the HTTP component is the only way ? or do we have any other option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create a HTTP-HTTPS global element and in security tab we can enter our keystore location, storePassword and keyPassword. later, we can enable the HTTPS in HTTP End point and refer the HTTPS global element created earlier .

```html
<https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-key-store path="\your path\.keystore" keyPassword="password" storePassword="password"/>
    </https:connector>
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="https://.." doc:name="HTTP"  transformer-refs="Message_Properties" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

TLS/SSL is a complex subject and requires knowledge on security algorithms, the keystores, the key ring management tool from Java and Mule itself.

The easies solution is what you mention indeed, to use Mule Studio will cover the 99% of the cases. I do recommend the following [reading](http://ricston.com/blog/configuring-https-mule/) in addition to the [reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference) to understand better how to perform an https call.